# Develop in-house app for another company signing with own Apple Developer Enterprise account

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, enterprise

My company has regular/yearly Apple Developer Program membership. At the moment I'm developing an app for another company, to be used only in-house. They are asking me to give them a signed IPA file.

Through the question:

- [Xcode : Can't Export in-house app .. provisioning profile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253899/xcode-cant-export-in-house-app-provisioning-profile-error)

I found out that I need to be enrolled in the Apple Developer Enterprise Program.

Now my query is, if my company takes the Apple Developer Enterprise membership, and we distribute and sign the app for in-house use, can my customer (the other company) use the IPA file with the signing from my Apple Developer Enterprise account for in-house use? Or must the siging be with their Enterprise account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not allow you to use company A's Enterprise account for signing apps to be distributed and used amongst employees of company B, unless company B is owned by company A.

A few other exceptions exist, for example for car manufacturers and their dealerships, and for hotel chains and their individual hotels. Also an exception exists if the employees of company B are actually physically located at company A's premises, and company A control the devices (i.e. they own the devices or they can remove these apps again). If your case do not fit these exceptions, you'll need individual approval from Apple for you case. This is normally not possible to get.

Comment: And if company B is inviting me in their team (they have an Apple Developer Enterprise Account), would it be possible for me to sign the app and delviere them the IPA file? Or is it not allowed to be member of another companies Apple Developer Enterprise team?

Comment: Yes, you can sign the app and deliver the IPA file. It is entirely allowed to have another company developing apps for you.

Comment: Thanks, then they have to invite me to their team, that I can develop for their in-house app store.